# How can I detect the Developer Tools is running on IE 10 with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

How can I detect the Developer Tools is running on IE 10 with JavaScript?

I tried:

```
if (console && console.log) {
   alert("Developer tools is running");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE 10 you can call

`window.__IE_DEVTOOLBAR_CONSOLE_COMMAND_LINE`

if it is an object the toolbar is open. (Be careful: it stays if you have opened the toolbar in the same 'window' before)
if it is 'undefined' the toolbar is closed.

Comment: Thank you! This help me a lot! Is there any more objects in window can detect the Developer Tools!

Comment: At the time I do not know more. Sorry.

Comment: OK， I checked the objects and functions in window when is developer tools is on and off, At present, Only the __IE_DEVTOOLBAR_CONSOLE_COMMAND_LINE is added. Thank you all the same!

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions of IE and in all other modern browsers you can't tell if the Developer Tools or Web Inspector are open. I assume the same is for IE10.

You can check if the browser supports console logging by using:

```
if ('console' in window) {
    if ('log' in console) {
        console.log('This will work.');
    }
}
```

IE8 and below may not support console logging, so it's wise to check if they do before logging to the console in your code.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK not really possible. `if( console.log )` would check if `console.log()` is an available function, so it will return true.

http://jsfiddle.net/cXBL9/

But of course this has nothing to do dev whether the tools are open or not.

Answer (score 0):

As Arbitter and Jazza have already stated, it's not really possible.

Perhaps not useful to you but the only way I've been able to interact with the Developer Tools is using the JavaScript statement:

```
debugger;
```

This will cause a breakpoint to be hit if debugging with Developer Tools.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FStatements%2Fdebugger

Comment: I know the "debugger" keyword, It is used to set breakpoint, Thank you all the same!